# Unpacking parameter packs multiple times

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, tuples, variadic-templates

Is it possible to unpack a parameter pack more than one time?

For example: I want to get a tuple containing 4 vectors - 2 of type int and 2 of type float.
To create such a tuple I want to use the syntax as follows:

```
ExampleClass<2, int, float> class;
```

Is it possible to create such a class? I'm thinking about something like this:

```
template <int numUnpacks, typename ... Types>
class ExampleClass
{
     using Types = std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>; // here i don't know how to unpack "std::vector<Types>...>" as often as "numUnpacks">
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using C++14's [`integer_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence). If you don't have that available, here's an [implementation](https://gitlab.com/redistd/integer_seq/blob/master/integer_seq.h) by [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely).

```
template <int numUnpacks, typename... Types>
struct ExampleClass
{
    template<typename T, size_t>
    using T_alias = T;

    template<typename T, size_t N, typename I = std::make_index_sequence<N>>
    struct repeat;

    template<typename T, size_t N, size_t... I>
    struct repeat<T, N, std::index_sequence<I...>> {
        using type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<T_alias<T, I>>()...));
    };

    using type = typename repeat<std::tuple<std::vector<Types>...>, numUnpacks>::type;
};
```

`ExampleClass<2, int, float>::type` is `std::tuple<std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>, std::vector<int>, std::vector<float>>`

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5fc80364e9d4b458)

Answer (score 1):

It seems straightforward with the usual recursive template partial specialization nonsense:

```
template<int n,class T,class... TT>
struct Impl;

template<int n,class... TT,class... UU>
struct Impl<n,std::tuple<TT...>,UU...> :
  Impl<n-1,std::tuple<TT...,UU...>,UU...> {};

template<class... TT,class... UU>  // just "class T" would be ambiguous
struct Impl<0,std::tuple<TT...>,UU...>
{using Types=std::tuple<std::vector<TT>...>;};

template<int n,class... TT>
struct ExampleClass : Impl<n,std::tuple<>,TT...> {};
```

The trick is creating a `tuple` early so that we can hold onto more than one template parameter pack at a time.